# Inverse Laplace transorm of $\sqrt s/(s^2+1)$

Tags: inverse-laplace

Can anyone calculate inverse Laplace of $$F(s)  = \frac{\sqrt{s}}{{s^2+1}} $$ ?

Comment: Maple:  $2\,\sqrt {{\frac {x}{\pi }}}
{\mbox{$_1$F$_2$}(1;\,3/4,5/4;\,-1/4\,{x}^{2})}
$

Comment: $\mathcal L^{-1}[F]$ [reduces to Fresnel integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049519).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\frac{\sqrt{s}}{{s^2+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{s}}{s}\frac{s}{s^2+1}
$$

and

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\right] = \frac{\phi(t)}{\sqrt{\pi t}},\ \ \ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^2+1}\right] =\phi(t)\cos t
$$

with $\phi(t)$ the Heaviside unit step function.

Comment: the problem is that the integral which shows up in Convolutions type cant be solved

Comment: It gives $$\sqrt{2} \left(C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{t}\right) \cos (t)+S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\sqrt{t}\right) \sin (t)\right)$$ with $C,S$ the corresponding Fresnel functions.

Answer (score 0):

With `CAS` help aka. `Mathematica`:

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{s}}{s^2+1}\right](t)=\frac{2 \sqrt{t} \, _1F_2\left(1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac{t^2}{4}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$
where:$\, _1F_2\left(1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac{t^2}{4}\right)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.

MMA code:

```
HoldForm[InverseLaplaceTransform[Sqrt[s]/(s^2 + 1), s, t] ==
(2 Sqrt[t]
HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {3/4, 5/4}, -((a t^2)/4)])/Sqrt[\[Pi]] // TeXForm
```

For general:

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{c s}}{a s^2+b}\right](t)=\frac{2 \sqrt{c} \sqrt{t} \,
   _1F_2\left(1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac{b t^2}{4 a}\right)}{a \sqrt{\pi }}$$